# How to show an Eclipse view like an intro

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am having an eclipse view which I am trying to display as an intro page. 
I am now opening the view with maximize but still the toolbars are visible.
So is there any way to make the view opening same as intro  page in eclipse.

I am not using intro as I want to make my own welcome page so I am not sure about the attitude of intro as it is mentioned that intro is basically for internal.
Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still [use `IIntroPart`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/intro/IIntroPart.html) (or have a look to [`CustomizableIntroPart`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/intro/config/CustomizableIntroPart.html)):

> The intro part is a visual component within the workbench responsible for introducing the product to new users. The intro part is typically shown the first time a product is started up.
>
> The intro part implementation is contributed to the workbench via the `org.eclipse.ui.intro` extension point.

(See this [thread as an example](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg02753.html)).

> There can be several intro part implementations, and associations between intro part implementations and products.
> The workbench will only make use of the intro part implementation for the current product (as given by [`Platform.getProduct()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform.html#getProduct()).
> There is at most one intro part instance in the entire workbench, and it resides in exactly one workbench window at a time.

See "[[Eclipse Intro] Make my own welcome page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118411/eclipse-intro-make-my-own-welcome-page/1129734#1129734)" as an example.

If you don't use it, at least have a look at the code of IIntroPart to see how it

Comment: I have my own plug-ins so Can I make my own intro page . And I am not clear about the point mentioned somewhere - "This extension point is currently provided for internal Eclipse SDK usage only. It should not be used for anything else except Eclipse SDK examples. "

Comment: I am actually not getting the concept behind the runtime product. I even followed your link but still I am not able to perform. Will you please explain me

Comment: @Abhishek: the idea is to associate an Intro page to a given product. Yes you can define your own intro page and define a product binding. See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_minimal.htm after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411446/welcome-menu-in-eclipse-product

Comment: @VonC .. I made a seperate plugin for minimal. Now in that there is a class name CustomizableIntroPart. Don't I need to code anything in that class file. Again, just clarify me the scenario if I am wrong. Do I need to create a plugin 1 for intro and plugin 2 for minimal config. Or in the same plugin I can make use of both the scenario. I am really confused about intro scenario. PLEASE GIVE ME STEP BY STEP PROCESS TO ACHIEVE INTRO PAGE ONCE

Comment: @Abhishek: the help page I mention is focused on illustrating just the intro page. But of course you can integrate all its suggestions within your own existing plugin, which would add the "intro page" feature to it. I am sorry I don't have a more step-by-step tutorial right now, but this might help: http://akravets.blogspot.com/2010/06/leavaraging-orgeclipseuiintrosamples.html

Comment: @VonC .. As per the link mentioned by you, it has been advised to create a minimal config if I want to show my own intro content. I created a project named org.eclipse.intro.minimal and did the same as mentioned and again I created a project named org.eclipse.self.introWelcome and in plugin.xml under introProductBinding tag I just added introID as org.eclipse.intro.minimal and ProdID as org.eclipse.sdk.ide. Now I run as>eclipse application and I did not find any option in help menu. Am I doing anything wrong.